# Tensorflow: How to convert to tflite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to use Tensorflow to convert the frozen pb to tflite, but actually the network's input type is '[None, None, None, 3]', and it cannot be supported. How to solve this problem?
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gen_tflite_coreml.py", line 32, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "/home/rafael/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py", line 335, in convert
    "invalid shape '{1}'.".format(_tensor_name(tensor), shape))
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'image' has invalid shape '[None, None, None, 3]'.
```

Comment: `None` is currently not supported outside of the 1st dimension. [This GitHub post](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21440) gives provides a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your model, you need to define your input_shape size.  For example, if you have a batch of 1 and and 300 x 300 rgb image you need to define your input shape size to be 1 x 300 x 300 x 3. (batch x width x height x rgb).

Comment: Can you provide an example code snippet for those parametersl?

Answer (score 0):

```
!tflite_convert \
  --output_file='/content/models/research/fine_tuned_model/frozen_inference_graph.tflite' \
  --graph_def_file='/content/models/research/fine_tuned_model/frozen_inference_graph.pb' \
  --inference_type=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
  --input_arrays='image_tensor' \
  --output_arrays='num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores','detection_classes' \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128 \
  --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
  --change_concat_input_ranges=false \
  --allow_nudging_weights_to_use_fast_gemm_kernel=true \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

This may help you. you just have to chnage input_array and output_arrays values